# Sort files by date created before showing it in the app

Tags: java, android

How do I sort files by date created before showing it in a listview within my own app?

I used files.lastModified(), which I do not want to use, because renaming would jumble it up. Is there anyway I can instead sort it by date creation? I've also tried mapping file names to time and date, but that's too tedious.

Comment: How would you get date? Have you stored in database?

Comment: @mins I've tried files.lastModified(), but that's not what I want. I want to sort it by date of file's creation. Seems like there's no API for that.

Comment: @Apurva, no I haven't. I just want to query a folder and retrieve files in the order of date of creation.

Comment: What version of Java do you use?

Comment: Thanks, but I really have no code to show for, except for the fact that I used files.lastModified(), which I do not want to use, because renaming would jumble it up. Anyways, I'll edit my description.

Comment: Then see my answer. There is an API for that starting with Java 7. Had you used Java 8 it would have been much more simple ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use Java 7, you can use the attributes API to obtain what you want.

Unfortunately however, getting access to the creation time requires that you read attributes which can lead to an IOException, so you have to deal with that...

Sample code:

```
private static FileTime getCreationTime(final Path path)
{
    final BasicFileAttributes attrs;
    try {
        attrs = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        return attrs.creationTime();
    } catch (IOException oops) {
        throw new RuntimeException("can't read attributes from " + path, oops);
    }
}

private static final Comparator<Path> CREATION_TIME_COMPARATOR
    = new Comparator<Path>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Path o1, final Path o2)
        {
            return getCreationTime(o1).compareTo(getCreationTime(o2));
        }
    };
```

Now, use `Files.newDirectoryStream()` to read the file entries into a list:

```
final Path baseDir = Paths.get("whever");

final List<Path> entries = new ArrayList<>();

for (final Path entry: Files.newDirectoryStream(baseDir))
    entries.add(entry);

Collections.sort(entries, CREATION_TIME_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll get back in a moment after I try it out myself. I'll hold the tick till then.

Comment: Note that alternatively you can use a `TreeSet` to store entries instead of only sorting after swallowing all entries